# Add routes to Dashing dashboard

Tags: routes, sinatra, dashing

How do I add a route in my dashboard that I can access, for example...

```
get '/:id' do
  protected!
  return params[:'id']
end
```

Which I can call from http://localhost:3030?id=1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to define a new application and call it inside the `config.ru` that gets created by Dashing. For instance, I created a new file called `my_app.rb` in a dashing repo with the following contents:

```
# my_app.rb

require 'sinatra/base'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/:id' do
    "My own custom route! And the id is #{params[:id]}"
  end
end
```

And included that app inside the `config.ru` like so:

```
# Created by dashing until Sinatra::Application
…
run Sinatra::Application

# added by us
run MyApp
```

And then when you run `dashing start`, the route we defined in our app gets called. But there's a problem with this approach in that you need to ensure that the routes being defined in `MyApp` won't conflict with those already defined by dashing. The other way to solve this is to let dashing run on a path other than the default `/`. There is a bit of documentation for [this approach in the Wiki](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/wiki/How-To:-Run-dashing-on-a-sub-path).